# When is Facebook turning off their session based auth?

Tags: facebook, session, authentication, deprecated

I've done some searching on Google and SO but I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Facebook has depreciated session based authentication in favour of OAuth 2.0. What I'm looking for is an announced date, or rough timeline as when they will be completely shutting down this form of authentication, and moving wholly to oauth.

We have a legacy system which is using session based authentication, and I want to make a case to the project manager that it needs to be changed sooner rather than later. This info will give me hard dates that I can put to him.

Citations and links to official Facebook developer pages a major plus :)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deadline seems to be October 1st 2011. Check the developer blog here:

- http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/501
- http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497

Comment: Seems that the date I'll be quoting is September 1st, but you are right in that overall it'll be October 1st. Thanks :)

Comment: @Chris I just took it from "This week, we announced an update to our Developer Roadmap that outlines a plan requiring all apps to migrate to OAuth 2.0, process the signed_request parameter, and obtain an SSL certificate by October 1" (first paragraph from the post 501). **Anyhow, you're right in this: it needs to be changed sooner rather than later.** Good luck with your boss ;)